# Move multiple rows at once with multiple conditions

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to iterate through each row at once with the for loop. When the row has the value "Done" in column P and "Update" in column M, I want to move the row to Done Sheet, if the row just has "Done" in P, I want it to move to Control Sheet.

```
function done() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();

  for(var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {

    var cP = s.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
    var cM = s.getRange(i, 10).getValue();

    if (cP == "Done" && cM == "Update") {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done Sheet"); // Logger.log(targetSheet); —> no output
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
      s.getRange(i, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(i);    
    }
    else if (cP == "Done") {
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Control Sheet");
      var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1); 
      s.getRange(i, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
      s.deleteRow(i);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the Logger.log() output of cP and cM?

Comment: it would be helpful if you can update your question to explain what *is* currently happening, does nothing move? only one moves? wrong data moves? do you get an error?  At a glance this looks OK, need to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: nothing moves i logged after the first if statement and i didnt get an output.

Comment: Could you log before the if statement and add the results to your question? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this code works for you:

```
function done() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Main Sheet'); // ss.getActiveSheet(); <= better call by name
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues(); // values keeps an array from the whole Sheet
  var doneSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Done Sheet");
  var ctrlSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Control Sheet");
  var rows_to_delete = []; // will receive the indexes to delete
  var doneSheetInputs = []; // will receive data to be inputed on doneSheet
  var ctrlSheetInputs = []; // will receive data to be inputed on ctrlSheet
  for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var cP = values[i][15]; //s.getRange(i, 13).getValue();
    var cM = values[i][12]; //s.getRange(i, 10).getValue();
    if (cP == "Done" && cM == "Update") {
      doneSheetInputs.push(values[i]);
      rows_to_delete.push(i + 1); // +1 because of difference in Array versus Google Sheets index
      Logger.log('Moving row ' + (i + 1) + ' to DONE');
    }
    else if (cP == "Done") {
      ctrlSheetInputs.push(values[i]);
      rows_to_delete.push(i + 1);
      Logger.log('Moving row ' + (i + 1) + ' to CONTROL');
    }
  }
  Logger.log('doneSheetInputs has ' + doneSheetInputs.length + ' entries');
  if (doneSheetInputs.length > 0) {
    doneSheet.getRange(doneSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, doneSheetInputs.length, doneSheetInputs[0].length).setValues(doneSheetInputs);
  }
  Logger.log('ctrlSheetInputs has ' + ctrlSheetInputs.length + ' entries');
  if (ctrlSheetInputs.length > 0) {
    ctrlSheet.getRange(ctrlSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, ctrlSheetInputs.length, ctrlSheetInputs[0].length).setValues(ctrlSheetInputs);
  }
  Logger.log('rows_to_delete has ' + rows_to_delete.length + ' entries');
  var rev = rows_to_delete.reverse(); // delete from bottom to top
  for (var i = 0; i < rev.length; i++) {
    s.deleteRow(rev[i]);
  }

}
```

It's not recommended to call `getRange().getValues()` so many times, specially inside a long `for` statement as described in [Google Apps Script Best Practices.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) I always try to call `getValues` before doing any iterations and return the values at the end of the code, in a batch operation.

**EDIT:** found out that the indexes for P and M columns were wrong - didn't check that out. Here is a working example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n68KqmI7HongEzJ_MSwmeQUqlAExjvCu2epEjEBZrlg/edit#gid=0 (send me request to access if you need it).

Comment: if i log with the values[i][12] i get an output, if i log the donesheetsinputs i dont get anything.  i will try to find the problem.

Comment: @Alessio I edited my answer. Please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: I also added some `Logger.log`, if you still can't figure it out, please paste what these logs give you